# LaTeX template for Oxford Journal about IT science [The Computer Journal]

Tags: journal-publishing, journal

I'm looking for LaTeX templates to typeset a working paper in a **Oxford journal's** preprint style. I'm also looking for BibTeX style files (templates) for Oxford Journal about IT science.

I found this link: http://www.oxfordjournals.org/for_authors/latex.html but it doesn't help much, I can't see anywhere any template (or `.sty` file) but I can download and work with.

Any ideas, links, help? I'm asking about **The Computer Journal** from Mathematics & Physical Sciences, here: http://www.oxfordjournals.org/our_journals/computer_journal/about.html. Unfortunately I cant see any `.tex` or `.sty` file there which I could use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On [the About page](http://www.oxfordjournals.org/our_journals/computer_journal/about.html), click [Instructions to authors](http://www.oxfordjournals.org/our_journals/computer_journal/for_authors/msprep_submission.html) in the right margin. Scroll down the page to *PREPARATION AND SUBMISSION OF THE MANUSCRIPT*, where you'll find the following:

> Papers must be clearly written in English. The text should be
>   presented on A4 or an equivalent size. Please submit your manuscript
>   in Computer Journal format using the LaTeX document preparation system
>   in conjunction with the [`comjnl.cls`](http://www.oxfordjournals.org/our_journals/computer_journal/for_authors/comjnl_latexprep2.zip) file. If this is not possible then
>   please ensure that the manuscript is in single-column format and
>   double line-spaced. Margins of at least 25 mm should be left around
>   all sides of the text. Please number each page but provide a short
>   running title on the title page only. Ensure that any unusual symbols
>   or letters are clearly identifiable. Manuscripts submitted in other
>   journal styles may be returned to you for re-formatting.
>
> The manuscript should contain the following information: the full and
>   a short title, and a complete list of authors, their affiliations and
>   addresses; the main text; all figures and tables, and references. The
>   corresponding author should be identified along with both his/her
>   postal and e-mail addresses, and telephone and fax numbers.

So you want to download this:

- http://www.oxfordjournals.org/our_journals/computer_journal/for_authors/comjnl_latexprep2.zip

This ZIP file contains the document class written for the journal (`comjnl.cls`), a BibTeX style file (`comjnl.bst`) and an example `.tex` file, `sample.tex`.

Comment: Many, many thanks! Compiled it with TeXMaker and worked :) Thanks again!